# Replacing exactly one element of an enumerable in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm quite new in using linq and have been playing around with it for some days now. My current problem is, that I have an enumerable and a specific object in this enumerable, which should be replaced with a new instance.

With a for-loop I would implement it like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Foo> ReplaceFirst(IEnumerable<Foo> enumerable, Foo obj)
{
    Foo[] array = enumerable.ToArray();
    bool used = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
        if(array[i] == obj)
        {
            array[i] = new Foo();
            used = true;
            break;
        }

        if (used)
            return array;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("obj not found in enumerable");
}
```

Now I'm searching for an implementation with linq. What I've found so far is this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Foo> ReplaceFirst(IEnumerable<Foo> enumerable, Foo obj)
{
    return enumerable.Contains(obj) 
            ? locatedPieces.TakeWhile(current => current != obj)
                .Append(new Foo())
                .Concat(enumerable.SkipWhile(current => current != obj)
                    .Skip(1)) 
            : throw new ArgumentException("obj not found in enumerable");
}
```

But I'm not really sure if this implementation is efficient since it has to iterate over the enumerable at least three times (at *Contains*, *TakeWhile* and *SkipWhile*).

Is there a better way to implement this function with linq, or should I keep using the for-loop variant?

Comment: You want to replace the properties or the whole instance ? the order is important?

Comment: I want to replace the the whole instance. Also the order is important, since there should only be one change on the first element. If there where more objects which are also equal, they should not be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the match with a new item if found, and throw if not found. It isn't very 'linqy', but it doesn't allocate, and it only iterates once.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<Foo> ReplaceFirst(IEnumerable<Foo> source, Foo target)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (found)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        else if (EqualityComparer<Foo>.Default.Equals(item, target))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return new Foo();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: From OP's comment above, it looks like they only want to change the first item. In which case you can just add another if condition - if(EqualityComparer... && !found)

Comment: I'd check `!found` first. `if (!found && EqualityComparer...)`. No sense in continuing to call `Equals` once you've found the first one.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest creating an extension method for this, something like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T oldVal, T newVal)
{
    return source.Select(e => EqualityComparer.Default.Equals(e, oldVal) ? newVal : e);
}
```

This will loop through the source and return the source elements except for those who == oldValue.

Also this uses deferred execution. The source is only enumerated when you start to enumerate the resulting IEnumerable. So if you change the source sequence after a call to this new Replace extension, the resulting sequence will yield this change, too.

Comment: I'd recommend using an equality comparer rather than `==` here... for example `EqualityComparer.Default.Equals(e, oldVal)`

Comment: Nifty. But this doesn't throw if the value isn't found, which I think OP wants. If it used `yield return` then that would be easy to implement.

Comment: True, if the user wanted to throw they could compare the two lists (original == replaced). If they match then throw

Comment: Updated answer to use Equality comparer

Comment: Comparing the two lists is potentially an expensive operation, if they are large.

Comment: I've also thought about an implementation like this, but i haven't found a way to limit it to only one change.

Comment: In which case I would go with @stuartd's answer.